# javascript jquery to check a checkbox if a number greate than 0 is inserted into a box

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox, onchange

I have two inputs, text and checkbox:

```
<input type="text" id="09_1" name="09_1" class="rounded"/>
<input type="checkbox" checked id="h09_1" name="h09_1" class="rounded"/>
```

the textbox `09_1` is updated with a number by jquery9result of database lookup)
I want the change of the input text to trigger a javascript function that checks the checkbox `h09_1`.

So something like:

```
  $("#09_1").on("change", function (event) {
            alert('test');

        });
```

This alert does not even work so this is not correct but where I am. I obviously want it to check the box rather than alert.

The checking of the checkbox must only happen if the number is greater than 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have a problem elsewhere. The code you posted above works in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/csbEz/

Comment: Thanks ryanbrill, this is not firing upon jquery changing the value of the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code isn't firing, you might try putting the 'on' on the document like so:

```
$(document).on("change", "#09_1", function (event) {

    if(!isNaN(this.value)){

           if(this.value > 0)
              $('#h09_1').attr('checked','checked');
           else 
              $('#h09_1').removeAttr('checked');

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks theWizardsBaker, this works 100$ is I manually change the textbox with a keyboard entry. it doesn't however change or fire when jquery updates the input box  from another function? any ideas? Thanks,

Comment: Hmm... You could try having the other function include .trigger('change') on the input box after it has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want the `keyup` event

http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/zkBCx/2/

```
$('#09_1').on('keyup', function () {
    $('#h09_1').prop('checked', +$(this).val() > 0);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Leon, works great on the fiddle. but in my codeigniter view itt still does not fire, even with a manual  key entry. I see that you have jquery 'on load' whilst my jquery is simply in the head in its own script tag. any other ideas? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkBCx/1/) it runs a value check when the input is changed.

```
 $('#09_1').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() > 0){
            $('#h09_1').attr('checked','checked');
        } else {
           $('#h09_1').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi McMastermind, thanks for your input. this change function still doesn't fire. the same applies as I described to Wing Leong? onnload?